# submit form using jquery not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am rendering partial form using jquery

```
$('.actCell').click(createClick);
function createClick() {
    var create = $(this).attr("create");
    $('#'+create).slideToggle();
    $.get('/policies/new', function(data) {

    });
}
```

Then there is another function that submit the form but submit is not working(it is missing submit function and doing the rails way)

```
$("#new_policy").submitWithAjax();
jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = function () {
    this.submit(function () {
        $('#createPolicy').slideToggle();
        $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
        return false;
    })
    return this;
};
```

The above function works if I stop using function which render partial form. Any help will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: If you are using a proper form ('<form>') you should better use the [`submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) function rather than a `$.post`. Also, if you are creating the form dynamically, you should use `on`.

Comment: "#new_policy" is a form element, right?

Comment: new_policy is the form id

Comment: Is the submit function in the same $(document).ready than the above part or it is loaded inside the policies/new page?

Comment: @Mir I have these functions in js files. Yes they are in same document ready.

Comment: Are you sure that the form submit event is delegated? If the form is dynamically loaded then it may not work for this reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out. This is what I am doing.

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form#new_policy', function() {
         $('#createPolicy').slideToggle();
             $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
             return false;

     });
```

Answer (score 2):

As the form is dynamic, you should use delegated event handlers:

```
jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = function () {
    $(document).on('submit', this.selector, function () {
        $('#createPolicy').slideToggle();
        $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
        return false;
    });
    return this;
};
```

inside a plugin, `this.selector` is the passed selector as a string, in this case `#new_policy`, so using that with `on()` will delegate the event to the document and filter on the selector.

Comment: unfortunately I am getting the same result

Comment: `this.selector` is not working. I debug it and remove `this.selector` with `this.$("#new_policy") then i was able to go to create method but  object was save it was redirected me to show page looks like it did not recocnizing that it is a js call

Comment: `this.selector` should always work within the scope of a plugin -> http://jsfiddle.net/KekDX/2/